Getting OSError: [WinError 126] when importing BERTopic
Everytime i want to import the bertopic package in python, i get an error:
OSError: [WinError 126] Kan opgegeven module niet vinden. Error loading "c:\Users\sienv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\fbgemm.dll" or one of its dependencies.
I already uninstalled & installed, i tried many things i found online but every time their is an error. Updating my windows, python, restart kernels, used other kernels, uninstalled & installed torch,... still the same error.

I had the same problem with a different dependency before. Try this.
